# Different Facebook pixels for each store/store-view/website

Tags: magento2, multistore, multisite, facebook-pixel

I have 4 shopify stores that I am hoping to convert into a single one using Magento. Far as I understand, it is possible to configure different prices, shipping methods, payment methods for each store.

What I have not any help with all the Googling is if I could use four different Facebook pixels each for the four stores.

So, any help with how to achieve it would be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an admin config with a facebook pixel id that can have a value for each store view. Then in a specific block you could inject the facebook pixel using the id value set for the store view in the admin.